# Spring + Hibernate Could not determine type Set

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been recently working on Hibernate and MVC. I have followed various tutorial and attempt to do a Many-To-Many relationship, but I keep getting the following error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: java.util.Set, at table: Group, for column
```

In my servlet-context.xml, I have the following:

```
<beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.model.Account</beans:value>
                <beans:value>com.model.Group</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
```

In my Group.class I have the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Group")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @Column(name="group_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String objectId;
    private String groupName;
    private Set<Account> accountList = new HashSet<Account>();
    // ... Getters and setters

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="objectId", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="objectId"))  
     public Set<Account> getAccountList() {
         return accountList;
     }
}
```

**UPDATED**
Account.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Account")
public class Account {

    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Id
    private String objectId;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="accountList")
    private Set<Group> groupList = new HashSet<Group>();
//...Getters and Setters
```

Group.class

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="Group")
    public class Group {
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;

        private String objectId;
        private String groupName;
        @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name="objectId", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="objectId"))  
        private Set<Account> accountList = new HashSet<Account>();

    }
```

Now I get the following error every time I try to save from the DAO implementation:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I do believe that the Set is causing the problem, but various tutorials were able to accomplish it, is there some extra procedure I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have given `@Id` annotation at the field, you will have to define the other annotations at field level and not at getter.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="objectId", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="group_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="objectId")) 
 private Set<Account> accountList = new HashSet<Account>();
```

would solve your issue.

Do not forget to follow the same in the `Account` class.

Comment: Hi, I receive a new mapping exception for the foreign key. Did I make my annotations wrong for the field level on the Account.class? See the UPDATED Section

Comment: Can you share the relevant code of your DAO implementation?

Comment: I have fixed he issue. I had to do a @JsonIgnore, It crashed because it went into an infinite loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Could give your Account class definition for @ManyToMany ?

Comment: I have placed my Account class @ManyToMany Relationship. I still can't figure why I get a mapping error.